# Copy/Paste and other things not working

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I have a macOS sierra 10.12.5 and every time I copy something from a text editor or web browser and paste it in to the terminal it pastes the last thing I pasted in terminal and not other apps.

Also when I download something and drag it to the desktop it turns into the last thing I edited.

When I try to copy an icon to an application nothing happens.