# Copy/Paste working inconsistently (El Capitan, Macbook Air)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, copy-paste

I'm using a MacBook Air from late 2010 or so, and I've recently noticed that my copy/paste abilities have become significantly reduced. Within an app itself it usually works without a hitch, but occasionally if I try to paste between apps (like, say, use a messaging app to send a link to someone), it'll usually either paste the last thing I copied within the app or nothing altogether. Right now, I'm just looking for some kind of quick, lasting fix, as this is making my usual workflow significantly more difficult.

Comment: Any similarities to these answers?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294951/copy-paste-and-other-things-not-working https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131873/copy-and-paste-stops-working You've kind of asked a yes/no question. Want to edit the "anyone else" to be more precise about what you want to accomplish? Perhaps how to inspect the copy buffer or check that an app isn't clearing the buffer periodically?

Comment: I have noticed that as well on High Siera, so now I am watching the Edit in the menu to see if it blinks when I Copy (cmd-c), indicating it copied it.

Comment: I have MacBook Air 2017 with High Sierra, and it sometimes misses the cmd-c for some reason. It could be just me, and I only notice it when I try to paste, then I have to go back wherever I was and do it again :( it sucks...but it shows nothing to do with hardware nor software (one thing that has not changed on MacBook Air is the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, it is possible for keyboard service to either die or become unresponsive. I've had this too, although I'm not really entirely sure under what circumstances. The following restarts it "gently", and may help you:

```
launchctl stop com.apple.pboard
launchctl start com.apple.pboard
```